# pass material ui styles to component - react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a functional component with React, I need to show SVG Icon based on state and I want to load the relevant icon

so the parent will show only call :

```
<icon classes:... , state..></icon>
```

1- how can I pass style and if it does not exist and use a default style in the child?

now I have smth like in the parent :

```
... createStyle
  IconSuccess: {
     fontSize: 20,
      width: 20,
    },
    IconWarning: {
      fontSize: 20,
      width: 20,
    },
```

but i want smth like :

```
 icon:{
  width:..
  font ..
  warning: { color}
  success: { color}
 }

then 

<IconChild state={state} classes={{ icon: itemStyle.icon}} />
```

this is work only if I pass specific style like:

```
 <IconChild state={state} classes={{ iconWarning: itemStyle.iconWarning}} />


then in the childCOmponent I am doing smth like:


 const classes = useStyles(props);
 if( props.state == 1){
  return <className={`${classes.iconWarning}`} />
 }
 else{
  return  <className={`${classes.iconSuccess}`} />
 }
```

**so basically  I am trying to understand how to create a really generic component that I can use and pass and that need a state to choose the specific icon and also from specific class**

do I need HOC ? or different approach

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to:

- Reuse some common properties like `width` and `fontSize`.
- Custom render other properties like `color`.

Then this is my approach:

- First, make new style for commonly used properties.
- Secondly, create new styles for conditional use of each state.
- Last, use something like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) to combine all classes.

So the main idea here is: instead of using one class for each item, now using two classes for each one. That's it!

```
const useStyles = withStyles({
  commonProperty: {
    fontSize: '20px',
    width: '20px',
  },
  successOnlyProperty: {
    color: 'green'
  },
  warningOnlyProperty: {
    color: 'orange'
  },
});
```